# Cannot instantiate non-existent class: ziparchive

Tags: php

I've a code that works correctly on test server but fails on live one (due to PHP version).

I'm getting this error:

`Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: ziparchive in /home/sites/www.example.com/web/zip.php on line 123`

and the code is:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
$zip->extractTo('unzipped/' . $id . '/');
$zip->close();
```

**How to make it working without ZipArchive class being available?**

---

Edit: I've used Mighty Google:

```
<?php
$zip = zip_open("zip.zip");
if ($zip) {
  while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
    $fp = fopen("zip/".zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "w");
    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
      $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
      fwrite($fp,"$buf");
      zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
      fclose($fp);
    }
  }
  zip_close($zip);
}
?>
```

Works great.

Comment: Are you sure line 123 is the one you provided? In the error message `ziparchive` is in lowercase, but in your code it's not.

Comment: That's the only place in the whole code this class is initiated

Comment: Do you have the Zip extension installed on your server?  Check your `phpinfo()`.

Comment: No, I don't - that's why it's not working

Comment: What's your php version on the second server?

Comment: @419: There you go.  Common problem, if you have control, recompile it with the `--enable-zip` option, among others.  If you have managed hosting, ask your hosting providers - warning, they might say no.

Comment: Please do not replace your questions with junk; if you want to remove them, you can delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the PHP version on both systems.
also check if php was compiled with the --enable-zip configure option

Install this module if needed.

check: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php for more information on how to install.

If you want to check if php has the right configure options or loaded modules you can use:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just have not enabled the ZipArchive module in your serverside php.ini?

Edit:
maybe you just forgot the brackets?
Try
    $zip = new ZipArchive();